# IE 9 CSS issue : height css attribute issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a following class applied to a div.

```
.pageGradientTop_T1 {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F7F7F7;
    border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    height: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

If the above class is applied to a div it will look like 3 lines of 1 px each (one top border, one bottom border and the middle is filled with the backgroud color) and the over all thing will look like a gradient.

For all browser except IE the height attribute is working fine.

I am not sure why the height attribute is not working for IE. I have even tried giving “ min-height: 2px; “ but that also didn’t work. It is automatically taking 18px as the minimum height and is not decreasing below that. But if you try to increase the height above 18px, it will work.

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sashwat

Comment: Specify the `line-height: xxpx;` in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used to `font-size` for ie

```
    .pageGradientTop_T1{
    font-size:0;  // for ie
line-height:0;  // for ie
    }
```

Comment: Thnx it worked. I do not know the reason for such behavior it will be great if you can explain me that.

Answer (score 0):

Add line-height to your class and set it to 0px:

```
.pageGradientTop_T1 { 
    line-height: 0px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F7F7F7; 
    border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1; 
    height: 2px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: even font-size: 0px has to be set. I do not know the reason for such behavior.

Comment: Cause the IE sees an container with text content, even when there isn't any text it takes the line-height/font-size and this is the minimum height of the container. Setting both to zero will reduce the min-height to zero, too.